# Getting issue in middleware of configureStore when update redux-toolkit to 2.0.1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

```js
export const store: AppStore = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
      immutableCheck: false
    }).concat([
      createStateSyncMiddleware({
        channel: "ketchcloth",
        broadcastChannelOption: { type: "localstorage", webWorkerSupport: false },
        blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/PURGE', 'persist/REHYDRATE']
      })
    ])
})
```

Here, I got the error

> TS2322: Type '(getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware) => Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>, ...Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>[]]>' is not assignable to type '(getDefaultMiddleware: GetDefaultMiddleware) => Tuple<Middlewares>'.
> Type 'Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>, ...Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>[]]>' is not assignable to type 'Tuple<Middlewares>'.
> Type '[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>, ...Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>[]]' is not assignable to type 'Middlewares'.
> Type 'ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction> | Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>'.
> Type 'ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>' is not assignable to type 'Middleware<{}, any, Dispatch>'.
> Types of parameters 'next' and 'next' are incompatible.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
> 48 | export const store: AppStore = configureStore({
> 49 |   reducer: rootReducer,
> 50 |   middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
> |   ^^^^^^^^^^
> 51 |     getDefaultMiddleware({
> 52 |       serializableCheck: false,
> 53 |       immutableCheck: false

I have tried `enhancers(getDefaultEnhancers)` but I didn't get any proper solution for this specific code.

Answer (score 1):

> Type 'Tuple<[ThunkMiddleware<any, UnknownAction>, ...Middleware<{},
> any, Dispatch>[]]>' is not assignable to type 'Tuple<Middlewares>'.

You are passing an array to the `getDefaultMiddleware.concat` method when you should just pass the middleware(s) directly.

```js
const stateSyncMiddleware = createStateSyncMiddleware({
  channel: "ketchcloth",
  broadcastChannelOption: { type: "localstorage", webWorkerSupport: false },
  blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/PURGE', 'persist/REHYDRATE']
});

export const store: AppStore = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
      immutableCheck: false
    }).concat(
      stateSyncMiddleware,
      /* other middlewares */
    );
});
```

Or spread the array into `.concat` if it's still really what you want to use.

```js
const stateSyncMiddleware = createStateSyncMiddleware({
  channel: "ketchcloth",
  broadcastChannelOption: { type: "localstorage", webWorkerSupport: false },
  blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/PURGE', 'persist/REHYDRATE']
});

export const store: AppStore = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
      immutableCheck: false
    }).concat(...[stateSyncMiddleware, /* other middlewares */])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to implement/configure the React Redux store in the React JS application. You can read more about React Redux from its official documentation. And redux-state-sync documentation. This redux-state-sync - plugin is not updated for 2 years. Might be it does not support the least Redux version.

Option 1:

```
import {
  createStateSyncMiddleware,
  initMessageListener,
} from "redux-state-sync";
const config = {
    channel: "ketchcloth",
    broadcastChannelOption: { type: "localstorage", webWorkerSupport: false },
    blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/PURGE', 'persist/REHYDRATE']
};
const middlewares = [createStateSyncMiddleware(config)];

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: false,
  immutableCheck: false
}).concat(middlewares),
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  preloadedState,
  enhancers: (getDefaultEnhancers) =>
    getDefaultEnhancers({
      autoBatch: false,
    }).concat(batchedSubscribe(debounceNotify)),
})
```

Option 2:

```
const config = {
    channel: "ketchcloth",
    broadcastChannelOption: { type: "localstorage", webWorkerSupport: false },
    blacklist: ['persist/PERSIST', 'persist/PURGE', 'persist/REHYDRATE']
};
const middlewares = [createStateSyncMiddleware(config)];
const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
```